# How to create a regex that find's the beginning of a tag to the end of a tag unless already closed? (>) not (/>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have created a function that takes in an html string as an argument, searches through the string for self-closing tags (`<br />`, `<img />`, `<input />`, `<col />`, `<hr />`). I haven't worked with regular expressions much and I was wondering if the ones I have would work for all instances. I'm not asking for you to check each one but how do I create a regular expression that find's the beginning of a tag to the end of a tag unless it is already closed?

e.g. Find `<br>` but not `<br />`

side note: I know there are more self-closing tags but this is all I need in my case.

**Update:** I'm aware that it is valid for HTML5. I am sending the HTML string to a web service (I have no control over the web service) that takes the HTML string and converts it to xml. I was getting an error that the img tag was not closed. I am not taking what is returned to replace what is already in HTML.

**Update 2:** I have significantly reduced the amount of code by putting every regex into one.

```js
var htmlStr = $("#content").html();

// add self-closing tags to html string (i.e. if <img> convert to <img />, if <br> convert to <br />)
function selfClosingTags(str) {
    // make sure self-closing tags aren't already closed (in regex [^\/]>)
    var selfClosingRegex = /<input[^/>]*>|<br[^/>]*>|<img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^/>]*>|<col[^/>]*>|<hr[^/>]*>/g;  // regex to find all self-closing tags

    // find all self closing tags and store in var
    var selfClosingTags = str.match(selfClosingRegex);

    var closingRegex = /[/]?>/g; // closing regex match /> or >

    selfClosingRegex = /<input[^/>]*>|<br[^/>]*>|<img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^/>]*>|<col[^/>]*>|<hr[^/>]*>/;       // regex to find first instance of self closing tag

    // loop through and close all self closing tags if not already closed
    for (var i = 0, len = selfClosingTags.length; i < len; i++) {
        str = str.replace(selfClosingRegex, selfClosingTags[i].replace(closingRegex, " />"));
    }

    return str;
}

console.log(selfClosingTags(htmlStr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" alt="Smiley face" width="100"></div>
  <br class="test">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <p>
    Test
  </p>
  <br class="test2">
  <p>
    Test 2
  </p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckbox">
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" alt="Smiley face" width="100">
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you need a function to find self-closing tags? HTML5 accepts you writing the tags without closing them at all; `<img src="">` is perfectly valid. Surely you can just search for the next occurrence of a `>`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm aware that it is valid for HTML5. I am sending the HTML string to a web service (I have no control over the web service) that takes the HTML string and converts it to xml. I was getting an error that the img tag was not closed. That is why I need this function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'll move it there when I get near a computer. But I'm not exactly asking for you to review my code. I am simply asking what would a proper regex be for something that ends with > but not />

Comment: I've actually decided against moving it but if other people believe it should be moved. I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

Match `<br>` but not `<br />`.

Use this regex.

```
/^<[^/<>]*>$/
```

```js
var re=/^<[^/<>]*>$/;
console.log(re.test("<br>"));
console.log(re.test("<br />"));
```